# Evaluate the integral: $\int \frac{x^2}{{(a + bx)}^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I need help to evaluate the integral of $$\int \frac{x^2}{{(a + bx)}^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
Here is my approach so far:

Let
$x = \frac{a}{b}\sin(t)$
so
$\mathrm{d}x = \frac{a}{b}\cos(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$

Therefore, $$
\int \frac{x^2}{{(a + bx)}^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
=\frac{a}{b^3}\int \frac{\sin^2 t}{(1+\sin t)^2} \, \mathrm{d}t$$
Let
$u = \sin t$
so
$\mathrm{d}u = \cos t \, \mathrm{d}t$
and
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{a}{b^3}\int \frac{\sin^2 t}{(1+\sin t)^2} \, \mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{a}{b^3}\int \frac{u^2}{(1+u)^2} \, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{a}{b^3}\left(-2\log|u+1| - \frac{1}{1+u} + u\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{b^3}\left(-2\log|\sin t+1| - \frac{1}{1+\sin t} + \sin t\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{b^3}\left(-2\log\left|1+\frac{bx}{a}\right| - \frac{a}{a+bx} + \frac{bx}{a}\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{b^3}\left(-2\log\left|\frac{a+bx}{a}\right| - \frac{a}{a+bx} + \frac{bx}{a} \right)
\end{align*}$$
But
$$\frac{1}{b^3} \left[(a+bx) - 2a\log(a+bx) - \frac{a^2}{a+bx} \right]
$$
is the given answer.

Can you show me where I made a mistake? If you can, show a different, faster way of solving this integral. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: try $u=a+bx$.

Comment: You did not make a mistake, as the difference between the two results is a constant. Your answer is slightly more general, as it is also valid when $a+bx<0$, while the given answer should include the term $-2a\log|a+bx|$ with the absolute value of the argument of the logarithm.

Comment: No, OP made several intermediate mistakes in their calculation. In particular, it looks like they forgot to account for their differential with both substitutions. If the answer is equivalent to the "actual" one, it's a fluke.

Comment: You start by making a trig substitution, followed immediately by a reverse trig substitution. You could have just subbed $x=\frac{au}{b}$ with way less work.

Comment: You "step jumping" doesn't make it good math, and it's precisely the kind of mistake a Calculus I student would make. You can either clarify your step-jumping, or show it explicitly for clarity. And graphs of functions are useful for, for instance, finding out whether two functions differ by a constant. Pure symbolic analysis is nice, but you would be very naive to ignore the variety of tools at your disposal. I did, however, retract the comment I think you're referring to, seeing as it turns out Desmos assumes $\log(\cdot) = \log_{10}(\cdot)$ and not $\ln(x)$, which explained matters.

Comment: I will clarify and add that "step jumping" and shoving in imaginary steps in your head also means there is more mental juggling. This makes it a lot harder to track down other mistakes made, and makes one prone to mistakes, which can be truly nasty for complicated questions. You also then make the assumption that - even if your answer is correct - anyone reading your work knows by default that you're skipping over those steps, which makes work significantly harder to follow. Hence in principle, up to limitations and considerations of audience, you should always fully show your work.

Comment: Other than aforementioned mistakes (which you explicitly asked for -- "Can you show me where I made a mistake?"), I already implied as much with my answer. Not sure what you're on about. I'm also not judging, I fell victim to the same silly mentalities when I was younger too. Reject my advice if you please, it's really no skin off my bones if you want life to be more difficult.

Comment: With all due respect to @JayadrataBanerjee step jumping doesn't make the intermediate steps correct.  The intermediate steps in question should have cos t as a factor are *incorrect* without it.

Comment: Sorry for all that talk! I guess I was really angry when I saw a negative comment instead of a positive one. This problem had been worrying me for 2 days. My teacher couldn't help solving this and I was stuck with that answer I got which didn't match the answer given in the book.

Answer (score 6):

One mistake arises here:
$$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\int \frac{x^2}{{(a + bx)}^2} \, \dd x =\frac{a}{b^3}\int \frac{\sin^2 t}{(1+\sin t)^2} \, \dd t$$
Do this calculation more carefully:
$$
\int \frac{ \frac{a^2}{b^2} \sin^2 t}{\left( a + b \frac a b \sin t\right)^2 } \, \frac a b \cos t \, \dd t
$$
Notice that you forgot the $\cos(t)$ tied to the differential. Factoring out carefully, we get
$$
\int \frac{ \frac{a^2}{b^2} \sin^2 t}{\left( a + b \frac a b \sin t\right)^2 } \, \frac a b \cos t \,\dd t
=  
\frac{a^2}{b^2} \frac a b \frac{1}{a^2} \int \frac{  \sin^2 t \cos t}{\left( 1 +   \sin t\right)^2 } \,\dd t
=  
\frac{a}{b^3} \int \frac{  \sin^2 t \cos t}{\left( 1 +   \sin t\right)^2 } \, \dd t
$$
Later on, you end up doing a substitution that yields $\cos(t) \, \dd t = \dd u$, which happens to negate your mistake, but this is purely dumb luck in this case. Be more mindful of replacing the differential in the future.

---

Technically speaking you should also include a constant of integration, this being an indefinite integral, but this is a minor oversight.

---

Your answer is ultimately equivalent to the claimed answer: any two "correct answers" to an indefinite integral will differ by a constant value, as per the mean value theorem. You can see this in their [Desmos graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hyn7yr1uzd):

[image]

Your solution in red has the added benefit of being slightly more general and correct, even, since the logarithm should be in absolute values.

To see the equivalence, first notice:
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{b^3} \left[(a+bx) - 2a\log(a+bx) - \frac{a^2}{a+bx} \right]  \\
&= \frac{a}{b^3} \left[  1+\frac b a x  - 2\log(a+bx) - \frac{a}{a+bx} \right]\\
&= \frac{a}{b^3} \left[  \frac b a x  - 2\log(a+bx) - \frac{a}{a+bx} \right] + \frac{a}{b^3}\\
&= \frac{a}{b^3} \left[  \frac b a x  - 2 \left( \log(a+bx) - \log(a) \right) - \frac{a}{a+bx} \right] + \frac{a}{b^3} - \frac{2a}{b^3} \log(a) \\
&= \frac{a}{b^3} \left[  \frac b a x  - 2 \log \left( \frac{a+bx}{a} \right) - \frac{a}{a+bx} \right] + \underbrace{\frac{a}{b^3} - \frac{2a}{b^3} \log(a)}_{\text{constant!}}
\end{align*}
$$
The key steps involved are:

- Factor out an $a$ from the brackets
- Add and subtract $- \frac{2a}{b^3} \log(a)$, to help form the quotient in your answer. When added, we can bring that inside the brackets.

Once one actually accounts for the absolute values, you thus see an entirely-equivalent answer.

---

To elaborate on another comment: notice that the composition of your substitutions ultimately amounts to letting
$$
x = \frac a b w
$$
Notice that that's what happens if you apply your substitutions in sequence:
$$
x \xrightarrow{x = \frac a b \sin t} \frac a b \sin t \xrightarrow{u = \sin t} \frac a b u
$$
Doing this at the outset would give you
$$
\frac{a}{b^3} \int \frac{u^2}{ \left( 1 +   u \right)^2} \, \dd u
$$
with comparatively minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{x^2}{{(a + bx)}^2} \,dx$$
Let $a+b x=t$ $$I=\frac 1{b^3}\int \frac{(t-a)^2}{t^2}\,dt=\frac 1{b^3}\int \left( 1-\frac{2
   a}{t}+\frac{a^2}{t^2} \right)\, dt$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int \frac{x^2}{(a+b x)^2} d x=&-\frac{1}{b} \int x^2 d\left(\frac{1}{a+b x}\right) \\
= & -\frac{x^2}{b(a+b x)}+\frac{2}{b} \int \frac{x}{a+b x} d x \\
= & -\frac{x^2}{b(a+b x)}+\frac{2}{b^2} \int \frac{a+b x-a}{a+b x} d x \\
= & -\frac{x^2}{b(a+b x)}+\frac{2}{b^2(a+b x)}-\frac{2 a}{b^2} \ln |a+b x|+C
\end{aligned}
$$